# How to change color of the coordinates?

Tags: google-sheets

How to change colour of the coordinates in Google Sheets?
As you can see **A** and **B** are green but **1** is gray.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only cells background properties are actively writable by a Google Sheets application.

Columns and Row indexes are highlighted with default colors to indicate a selection status (*blue highlighting*) and filtered status (*green highlighting*).

These properties are **not** customizable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, so you can't colour the coordinates.
They turn green once you apply a sorting filter.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, google sheets does not allow to change the coordinates color.

The colors will change depending on the cells that are selected:

[image]